# HTML div needs to be on top of all other controls

Tags: html, css, opacity

Some controls on the parent screen are bleeding through the div (see image). I need this div to be on top of all other controls. Right now the radio button list and the tabs are somehow on top.

[image]

Here is the declaration of the dialog box:

```
<div id="divSaveAnalysis" style="display: block; opacity: 100; width: 350px; font-size: 40px; position: absolute; top: 35px; left: 100px; background-color: rgb(247, 219, 111); padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #000;">
    <div id="saving" style="font-size:medium; font-weight:bold;">
        <span id="savingSpan" style="font-size: xx-large">Saving Analysis...</span>
        <img src="css/images/Indicators/Activity/GearGreen_66x66.gif" style="float: right; height: 80px;"
            title="Saving FLSA Analysis" alt="Saving..." />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div><span id="savingReport" style="font-size: small;"></span></div>
        <div><span id="savingInputs" style="font-size: small;"></span></div>
        <div><span id="savingResults" style="font-size: small;"></span></div>
        <div><span id="savingComplete" style="font-size: small;"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The computed styles for the div are:

```
background-color: rgb(247, 219, 111);
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 0.9090908765792847px;
border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 0.9090908765792847px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 0.9090908765792847px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 0.9090908765792847px;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: none;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
height: auto;
left: 100px;
line-height: 17.99715805053711px;
opacity: 1;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-top: 15px;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
top: 35px;
visibility: visible;
width: 350px;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `z-index` to the div that needs to be on top?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PW32t/), which is working for me in Chrome latest. It is possible your radio buttons have been given a higher `z-index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use z-index to change the way the contact stacks. By default it's based of the order the content loads with the page.

By default z-index is 'auto'. Try setting it to an integer like 100.

```
z-index:100;
position:absolute;
```

When you use z-index you have to also change the position value for the content.

You can read more about z-index here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

Comment: z-index worked and my code already had position:absolute. Now I just need to understand how they interact.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the z-index will control the stacked order of elements.

```
#divSaveAnalysis {
  z-index:10000;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no reason for having a `z-index` set to 10000, if no other `z-index` is set on the page, `z-index:1;` is enough to push it higher than everything else.. doing something like that will only cause you headaches when you come to place something else on top of the page in the future... use your `z-index`'es responsibly!

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, but since I didn't have access to the entire page I wanted to play it safe to ensure the issue was fixed. But yes, `z-index:1;` is the way to go most often.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add property of
`z-index:99999;`

and make sure to add

```
position: relative;
```

for the z-index to work.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no reason for having a `z-index` set to 99999, if no other `z-index` is set on the page, `z-index:1;` is enough to push it higher than everything else.. doing something like that will only cause you headaches when you come to place something else on top of the page in the future... use your `z-index`'es responsibly!